# how to read decimal and date from mariadb to python?

Tags: mysql, pandas, mariadb

I am reading data from MariaDB database from python using mysql.connector

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
cnx = mysql.connect(user='',pwd='',host='',port='',database='')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
query = 'select * from …….'
cursor.execute(query,(0,2))
my_list = []
for row in cursor:
    my_list.append(row)
print(my_list)

data = [('t10djm6','NM_INIT', 3920, datetime.date(2018, 1, 29),Decimal('4.310'), Decimal('5000.00'), 1),
 ('t10djm6','CHECK_INIT', 3920,datetime.date(2018, 1, 29),Decimal('4.330'), Decimal('5020.00'), 2)]

sql_data = pd.DataFrame(data = data,columns=[……………..])
```

the date and decimal values coming as datetime.date(2018, 1, 29) which is 2018-1-29 and Decimal('5000.00') which is 5000.00

The values are in a tuple and I am storing that as list of tuples to convert into pandas dataframe
May I know how to convert the date and decimal values to store in dataframe

I tried import datatime and import decimal as Decimal, but getting

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

for decimal

May I know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `import decimal as Decimal` then the name `Decimal` refers to the module `decimal` and the module is not callable. What you need is:

```
from decimal import Decimal
```